# CrmServiceContext not loading relationship data with CRM 2015 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I am in process to convert/upgrade an application to use CRM 2015 Online instead of CRM 2011. But it is failing to load relationship data with connection using CRM 2015. However it is working with CRM 2011. I have created the Entity wrapper using latest CRM 2015 SDK.

**Code To Retrieve Order**

```cs
var context = GetNewContext();

var ordersToProcess = (from o in context.SalesOrderSet
                       where o.SalesOrderId == orderId
                       select o).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var salesOrder in ordersToProcess)
{
    // *** Error Here ***
    // *** CRM 2015 Code is throwing error here because transactioncurrency_salesorder is null ***
    var urrencyCode =
             salesOrder.transactioncurrency_salesorder.ISOCurrencyCode;
}
```

**Generate Connection using CRM 2011 Code**

```cs
public static CrmServiceContext GetNewContext(CrmConnection conn)
{
    var context = new CrmServiceContext(conn);
    return context;
}
```

**Generate Connection using CRM 2015 Online Code**

```cs
public static IOrganizationService GetNewService(CrmConnection conn)
{
    var service = new OrganizationService(conn);
    return service;
}

public static CrmServiceContext GetNewContext(CrmConnection conn)
{
    var context = new CrmServiceContext(GetNewService(conn));
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Is the transactioncurrency_salesorder attribute null?  or is the salesOrder object null?  to me it seems like if the salesOrder object is populated, then it's not necessarily an issue with the context.

Comment: `salesOrder` does have value but `transactioncurrency_salesorder` is null with 2015 online context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transactioncurrency_salesorder` is a N:1-relationship between Sales Order and Currency.

If your context inherits from `OrganizationServiceContext` (which I assume is the case for your 2015-code), these relationships are not loaded by default. You can have them lazy loaded by calling [LoadProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg307150.aspx) before accessing the relationship:

```
context.LoadProperty(salesOrder, "transactioncurrency_salesorder");
```

If your context inherits from `CrmOrganizationServiceContext` (which I assume is the case for your 2011-code), [relationships are automatically lazy loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270081/what-changes-does-referencing-codegeneration-codecustomization-make-to-the-early).

Alternatively, if you do not need to actually load the Currency itself (and only want the name or Guid of the Currency), you can use the EntityReference `TransactionCurrencyId`. This is always set, also without calling `LoadProperty`. You could e.g. get the name of the Currency as follows:

```
salesOrder.TransactionCurrencyId.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand but I am just wondering how it is working with 2011! I have not made any code changes.

Comment: What are the differences between your 2011 context and your 2015 context? Do they both inherit from the same class? It might be that your 2011 context inherits from CrmOrganizationServiceContext (which has implicit lazy loading) and that your 2015 context inherits from OrganizationServiceContext. See the following for a link to explanations and arguments for CrmSvcUtil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270081/what-changes-does-referencing-codegeneration-codecustomization-make-to-the-early

Comment: Thanks @Henrik, it sorted the issue. Above Link is quite useful.